# Is it possible tofind a subset of F_p for large p such that no solutions exist

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, math, applications

I'm aware that neural networks are probably not designed to do that, however asking hypothetically:
I have a question regarding the possibility of identifying a subset of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in which a given equation has no solutions.Specifically, I'm dealing with a fourth-degree homogeneous polynomial involving four variables. My goal is to identify a subset of $\mathbb{F}_p$ called $A$ such that when my variables belong to this subset, the equation has no solutions.

To illustrate this concept with a simple example, consider the equation $x + y + z = 0$. If I choose the set $A$ to be $\{1, 2, ..., (p-1)/4\}$, then this equation has no solutions when the variables fall within this set.

Is it feasible to find such subsets for more complex equations as well?

Thank you for your assistance.